# PHP encrypted string different from C#

Tags: c#, php

I'm trying to encrypt a string in C# and PHP and I obviously want them to return the same value.

C# code:

```
 public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt)
    {

        int intLenght = toEncrypt.Length - 1;
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] ToEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PKey));

        hashmd5.Clear();
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(ToEncryptArray, 0, ToEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        string res = System.Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);

        return res;
    }
```

PHP Code:

```
function decryptCode(){
$hash = base64_encode(md5($key, true));
$toDeco = checkCode();
if(!$toDeco)
{
    die("Invalid Code!");
}
$deco = utf8_decode($toDeco);

$data = openssl_encrypt($deco, 'DES-ECB', $key);




die($data);
}
```

What C# returns:  0vY6hKcRYLA=

What PHP returns: 0L9AwtASbvg=

The keys (pKey and $key) are both the same of course. I check the md5 hashes and those are the same so that's not the issue.

And yes I know that this method (triple des, ecb) isn't very secure at all but it's just for a school project.

What is wrong with the PHP code here? Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: First rule to programming, learn how to debug. Does `C# keyArray` and `php $hash` contain the same value? Because that is most likely where your issue is.

Comment: So interesting and disappointing that a school is using 3DES for teaching encryption, it not only should not be used in new code but has more pitfalls that do not help understanding encryption.